# DelayedJob doesn't release memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory-leaks, delayed-job

I'm using Puma server and DelayedJob.
It seems that the memory taken by each job isn't released and I slowly get a bloat causing me to restart my dyno (Heroku).

Any reason why the dyno won't return to the same memory usage figure before the job was performed?

Any way to force releasing it? I tried calling GC but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 5):

You can have one of the following problems. Or actually all of them:

**Number 1**. This is not an actual problem, but a misconception about how Ruby releases memory to operating system. Short answer: it doesn't. Long answer: Ruby manages an internal list of free objects. Whenever your program needs to allocate new objects, it will get those objects from this free list. If there are no more objects there, Ruby will allocate new memory from operating system. When objects are garbage collected they go back to the free list. So Ruby still have the allocated memory. To illustrate it better, imagine that your program is normally using 100 MB. When at some point program will allocate 1 GB, it will hold this memory until you restart it.

There are some good resource to learn more about it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/) and [here](http://www.schneems.com/2015/05/11/how-ruby-uses-memory.html).

What you should do is to increase your dyno size and monitor your memory usage over time. It should stabilize at some level. This will show you your normal memory usage.

**Number 2**. You can have an actual memory leak. It can be in your code or in some gem. Check out [this repository](https://github.com/ASoftCo/leaky-gems), it contains information about well known memory leaks and other memory issues in popular gems. `delayed_job` is actually listed there.

**Number 3**. You may have unoptimized code that is using more memory than needed and you should try to investigate memory usage and try to decrease it. If you are processing large files, maybe you should do it in smaller batches etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michal. I'm using lots of hashes with symbols as keys. Although these hashes are no longer referenced , switching to string keys might be useful? Since symbols are more resilient to garbage collecting?